Docker push starts but stuck on Pushing
When i try to push my image to the docker hub, it initiates but as soon as it goes from Waiting -> Pushing, its just stuck there, nothing happends. The same happends to any layer it tries to Push.

I dont recieve any error message it simply just get stuck there.
I am using a free acount with 1 repository.
I am properly logged in using docker login -u <username>
The repository on my hub account matches the tag name of my docker image

Any ideas what could be the problem?


Hmm maybe something like a firewall/network issue? Can't see anything else here
